# Weierstrass form of genus one $y^{10} z^{30} - 8000 y^{4} z^{20} + 12800000 z^{20} + 1600 y^{2} z^{10} - 64=0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Related to the n-conjecture.

We are looking for Weierstrass form and map from it of the genus one curve:

$$ y^{10} z^{30} - 8000 y^{4} z^{20} + 12800000 z^{20} + 1600 y^{2} z^{10} - 64=0 $$

It is of degree $40$ and has only five monomials.

---

**Added** We suspect there are finite number of rational points (likely none).

So the Weierstrass form may be over number field with monic defining polynomial with integer coefficients. The rank must be positive in addition. This relaxation might help Magma (we don't have it).

---

Maple gave weird error.

In machine readable form:

```
y^10*z^30-8000*y^4*z^20+1600*z^10*y^2+12800000*z^20-64
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(a) The given curve is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, but reducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})$. So it does not have a Weierstrass form, and each rational point has to be a singularity. The curve however does not have rational singularities (there are two on the projective completion though).

(b) From the latest comments by the OP it has become clear that he wants a Weierstrass model for a *component* of the curve. Set $\alpha=\sqrt[5]{2}$. Then the curve given by $y^2z^6 + 20\alpha^2z^4 -2\alpha=0$ is one of the algebraically conjugate components. Over $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\sqrt[4]{20})$ this is easily brought into Weierstrassform by hand.

*What follows was written before I realized that the curve isn't absolutely irreducible. So it may help in such situations, though it has little value (and lacking correctness) here.*

The following works: Set $F(y,z)=y^{5} z^{3} - 8000 y^{2} z^{2} + 12800000 z^{2} + 1600 y z - 64$. Then your elliptic curve $C$ is the solution set of $F(y^2,z^{10})=0$. Let $C'$ and $X$ be the solution sets of $F(y^2,z)=0$ and $F(y,z)=0$. So there are natural covers $C\to C'\to X$. Note that $C'$ has genus $1$, and $X$ has genus $0$.

Maple easily finds a rational parametrizaton of $X$. After some simplifications we see that $y=s^3-20s$, $z=\frac{4}{s^5}$ is a parametrization of $F(y,z)=0$.

So a Weierstrass form of $C'$ is given by $E':y^2=s^3-20s$, and $\alpha':E'\to C'$, $(s,y)\mapsto(\frac{4}{s^5},y)$ is birational. Let $\alpha:E\to C$ be a birational map (defined over some number field) of a Weierstrass model $E$ of $C$, and $\psi:C\to C'$ be the natural map $(z,y)\mapsto (z^{10},y)$.

Then $\alpha'^{-1}\circ\psi\circ\alpha$ is an isogeny $E\to E'$ of degree $10$.

If a non-singular model of $C$ had a rational point, then $E$ and $\alpha$ could be defined over $\mathbb Q$, and $E'$ would have an isogeny of degree $10$ defined over $\mathbb Q$. However, the $5$-division polynomial of $E'$ does not have a quadratic factor over $\mathbb Q$, so $E'$ and then also $E$ has no rational isogeny of degree $5$, and therefore also none of degree $10$.

In particular, as expected by the OP, $C$ has only finitely many rational points.

How to explicitly find $E$ and $\alpha$? Using (for instance) Sage one can find $E$ and an isogeny $\mu:E\to E'$ of degree $10$. (First find the degree $10$ isogeny $E'\to E$, then take its dual.) Finding $\alpha$ amounts to expressing a generic point $(z,y)\in C$ in terms of the generic point $(u,v)\in E$. This should be doable via $(z^{10},y)=\psi((z,y))=\alpha'(\mu((u,v))$, because we can compute everything on the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you. I get another Maple error, possibly due to different version or other reasons.

Comment: Are you sure about infinitely many rational points? On y^2=s^3-20s we have infinitely often $s=s'^2$. This makes z=4/s'^10. $z$ must be tenth power and it is not. It is tenth power in a number field where $4$ is. Would you please give few rational points?

Comment: @joro: You are right, $C$ indeed has only finitely many rational points. I amended my answer.

Comment: I don't think it has any rational points, have you found one?

Comment: @joro: I just noticed that your curve isn't absolutely irreducible, while it is reducible over the rationals! So that tremendously simplifies things, because only singularities can be rational points! (But non of them, except for two points at infinity, are rational.) I guess this also explains the error messages in Maple when trying to find the Weierstrassform, because the program certainly expects an absolutely irreducible curve of genus $1$.

Comment: Why don't you explicitly include the positive result over a number field? On y^2=s^3-20s, by the multiplication by two map $s$ is square infinitely often. This make $z$ on $F$ four times tenth power, so when $4$ is tenth power we have points in the NF. Is it not allowed to find Weierstrass form of non-absolutely irreducible genus 1 curve? It is well defined in the above NF and I checked it in sage. (Have seen strange errors in many CASes).

Comment: A non-singular curve given in Weierstrass form is absolutely irreducible, hence so is every curve which is birationally equivalent (no matter over which field) to this curve. But your curve factors over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})$.

Comment: Don't understand your last comment. I have Weierstrass form of my curve over your number field and it is birationally equivalent to the original curve.

Comment: @joro: What do you mean? In your question, you *ask* for a Weierstrass form! So what does your comment mean that you *have* a Weierstrass form which is birationally equivalent to the given curve? By the way, I still believe that I correctly answered your question.

Comment: I discovered the Weierstrass form over NF with your great help, thanks. Didn't understand your previous comment.

Comment: I still get error in Maple, does this work for you in Maple? `p:=y^10*z^30-8000*y^4*z^20+1600*z^10*y^2+12800000*z^20-64:fa:=evala(AFactor(p)):q:=op(fa)[1]:genus(q,y,z);Weierstrassform(q,y,z,u,v);`

Comment: Maple keeps running, no error and no result either. But once you have $q$ there is no need no employ Maple: $q$ has degree $2$ in $y$, so an easy transformation gives you a hyperelliptic curve $y^2=h(z)$ with $h$ of degree $3$ or $4$. If $h$ has degree $4$, there is another trick to get it down to degree $3$. By the way: What you are doing is that you compute a Weierstrass form of an absolutely irreducible *component* of your original curve. This is in line with what I said: Your original curve has *no* Weierstrass normal form!

Comment: Yes, I noticed it is easy to solve the $q$. I get error "Reducible root detected" quite soon.